# removing magento favicon from view source & image pages?

Tags: magento, favicon

we've changed our [magento site's](http://akaknits.com/) favicon on both the front-end & back-end but the default magento favicon is still showing up when you view source or image in a new tab on chrome?

Any idea how we can change this?

I've tried removing  every magento favicon.ico file from our server but with no luck.

Comment: if yout changed it properly the it should be your browser's cache. clean or try a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cache, it should be visible to you. I cannot see magento faviocn on your website. [image]

Comment: thanks,  I had actually tried that before but realized I only cleared the previous 4 weeks of my cache

Comment: really strange - It's still showing up under 'view image in new tab' for me & I've definitely cleared my cache properly.  Is it showing on your chrome browser?  maybe it is a bug with chrome